# How to get the maximum of more than 2 numbers in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, methods

I have an array of five numbers and an array of 2 numbers.  How would I find out the largest number among these 7 numbers?  Is there a method that can make things easier?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
int[] array1 = { 0, 1, 5, 2, 8 };
int[] array2 = { 9, 4 };

int max = array1.Concat(array2).Max();
// max == 9
```

Comment: Very odd, i tried to vote you up. It dropped your vote count to 0 and said vote limit reached. I tried it again and it bumped you up to 2, giving the same message! :S

Answer (score 12):

You can try

```
decimal max = Math.Max(arr1.Max(), arr2.Max());
```

Comment: +1 for not wasting time and memory concatenating the arrays first

Comment: @Jason Williams - Concat doesn't allocate an array and so is just as good as this solution.

Answer (score 5):

Straightforward way:

```
Math.Max(Math.Max(a,b), c)//on and on for the number of numbers you have
```

using LINQ:

```
int[] arr1;
int[] arr2;
int highest = (from number in new List<int>(arr1).AddRange(arr2)
               orderby number descending
               select number).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using 3.5 you could use Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
var values = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
var maxValue = values.Max();
```

Comment: Forget my post, I missed the bit where you said 2 arrays.  280's response hit the nail on the head.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the dependency is `System.Linq`. Without that include (which I understand Visual Studio includes by default for _most_ C# projects), you get an error stating that "int[] does not have a method Max()"