# Using "if" statement to remove min/max user input data

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, well, coding in general.
I have done fairly well by myself to date, in this introduction course I am taking, but I ran into a road bump.

I am trying to figure out how to code a if statement that will run inside a loop to analyze 5 different ints as they are entered and to put the max int and min int seperatly so that I can ue the remaining three ints to make a calculation.
To be exact, validate user input and remove the min/max user input to average the remaining three.

PS, I tried an array but for some reason it wasn't working well.  I don't have the code as I'm at work right now though.  I was told in a lecture that an if statement should be used but arrays are possible too.

Thank you for your time and any possible answers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userIsFinished = "";
            string name, city, value;
            double rating, avg = 0;
            double[] array1 = new double[5];
            double max = 0;
            double min = double.MaxValue;
            double score, totalScore = 0;


            //get basic information
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter divers name.");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the divers city.");
                city = Console.ReadLine();



                //get and validate user input for 1 dive rating
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a dive rating between 1.00 and 1.67.");
                rating = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while (rating < 1 || rating > 1.69)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops, you entered an invalid number. Please, enter a dive rating between 1.00 and 1.67.");
                    rating = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

                // get and validate user input for 5 judge scores
                for (int s = 1; s <= 5; s++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the score for judge {0}.", s);
                    value = Console.ReadLine();
                    score = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                    while (score < 0 || score > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, please enter a number in between 0 - 10.");
                        score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    array1[s] = Convert.ToDouble(score);     //----this line keeps throwing an exception
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

                //calculate totalScore by dropping min/max scores and averaging them times dive rating
                foreach (int i in array1)
                {
                    if (i > max)
                        max = i;
                    if (i < min)
                        min = i;
                    avg += i;
                }
                totalScore = avg * rating;

                //Print gathered and calculated information
                Console.WriteLine("Divers name: {0}", name);
                Console.WriteLine("Divers city: {0}", city);
                Console.WriteLine("Dive degree of difficulty: {0}", rating);
                Console.WriteLine("Total dive score is: {0}", totalScore);

                // Ask if user wants to process another diver and continue or exit program
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another divers information? [Y]es [N]o: ");
                userIsFinished = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while
            (userIsFinished.ToLower() != "n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Try to first formulate a problem statement, and then solve it in [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). Start with something like: "The user inputs five numbers. Of those, remove the highest and lowest value, and return the average of the remaining numbers". :-)

Comment: I got one of them with me, at work at the moment, here it is

Comment: Just a tip: Check out this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811756/how-to-get-the-maximum-of-more-than-2-numbers-in-visual-c)

Comment: if (score > highestScore) score = highestScore
        else if (score < lowestScore) score = lowestScore
    else score + totalScore = totalScore
     }

Comment: Thanks John, I'll check that link  :)

Comment: I got my full code edited into the original post.  Still getting stuck on the code part about the 5 scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your question... You want to know, the max and min about 5 values, and the avarage about the three others...

```
int[] n = { 4, 7, 29, 3, 87 };
int max = 0;
int min = int.MaxValue;
double avg = 0;

foreach (int i in n)
{
    if (i > max)
        max = i;

    if (i < min)
       min = i;

   avg += i;
}

avg = avg / n.Count - 2;
```

Comment: I got the full code up, if ya could, give it a look over for me?

Answer (score 2):

or you can go list route and

```
List<int> apples = new List<int>();
apples.Add(31);
apples.Add(34);
apples.Add(100);
apples.Add(57);
apples.Add(1);
int min = apples.Min();
int max = apples.Max();
apples.Remove(min);
apples.Remove(max);
decimal average = (decimal)(apples.Sum()) / apples.Count;
```

Comment: After all that `Max()`,`Min()` why don't you use `apples.Average()`

Comment: Thanks a ton, sadly, we aren't that far into class yet but this looks interesting and I will start studying on it before we get that far.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 int[] a = new int[5];
 int minpos;
 int maxpos;
 int min = Int32.MaxValue;
 int max = a[0];
 int temp = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(" Enter number " + (i + 1));
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp);
    a[i] = temp;

    //Decision Making Logic 

    if (min > temp)
    {
        min = temp;
        minpos = i;
    }
    if (max < temp)
    {
        max = temp;
        maxpos = i;
    }
}
```

//At the end of this loop you will see that minpos contains the index of minimum element
//and maxpos contains index of maximum element,values in remaining indeces contain elements that are neither max or min in that //collection

Comment: iam really sorry if you find the code illegible, as iam yet to get in synch with the code formating

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it appears I needed a good night of sleep.  Thanks a ton for all these helpful answers as I'm sure I will be delving into those methods soon and it will be good to be able to get a head start on them.  Here is my code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userIsFinished = "";
            string name, city;
            double rating, avg = 0;
            double max = 0;
            double min = 10;
            double score, value = 0, totalScore = 0, finalScore = 0;


            //get basic information
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter divers name.");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the divers city.");
                city = Console.ReadLine();



                //get and validate user input for 1 dive rating
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a dive rating between 1.00 and 1.67.");
                rating = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while (rating < 1 || rating > 1.69)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops, you entered an invalid number. Please, enter a dive rating between 1.00 and 1.67.");
                    rating = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

                // get and validate user input for 5 judge scores
                for (int s = 1; s <= 5; s++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the score for judge {0}.", s);
                    score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                    while (score < 0 || score > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, please enter a number in between 0 - 10.");
                        score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    if (score > max)
                        max = score;
                    if (score < min)
                        min = score;

                    totalScore = score + totalScore;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
                \\Calculate values
                value = totalScore - max - min;
                avg = value / 3;
                finalScore = avg * rating;

                //Print gathered and calculated information
                Console.WriteLine("Divers name: {0}", name);
                Console.WriteLine("Divers city: {0}", city);
                Console.WriteLine("Dive degree of difficulty: {0}", rating);
                Console.WriteLine("Total dive score is: {0}", finalScore);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                // Ask if user wants to process another diver and continue or exit program
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another divers information? [Y]es [N]o: ");
                userIsFinished = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while
            (userIsFinished.ToLower() != "n");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```